# Who is responsible for more deaths: Voldemort or Grindelwald?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, gellert-grindelwald

There have been claims made that Grindelwald is almost unfathomably much more evil than Voldemort, comparing the former to Hitler (though there is more to that comparison than just "evil", it also hearkens back to Grindelwald's connection to World War II).

**Which of the two is responsible for the most deaths?**

In the same way that dictators are held responsible for the deaths they caused and killings they ordered (without necessarily having personally murdered all those people), I want to know which of the two dark wizards, Grindelwald or Voldemort, is responsible for the most deaths.
If you can break your answer down into (estimated) total deaths, and personal killings, even better.

Related: [Who was more skilled at magic: Grindelwald or Voldemort? [closed]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55666/who-was-more-skilled-at-magic-grindelwald-or-voldemort)

Comment: I would have to say it’s still too opinion-based. There aren’t really “rules” in the *Harry Potter* universe for being evil (unlike, say, D&D). Is Grindelwald  more evil because he was active in all of Europe? Is Voldemort more evil because he made Horcruxes? Is Grindelwald more evil because he betrayed his friend? Is Voldemort more evil because he had no friends?

Comment: well voldemort is incapable of love, grindelwald has probably been in love.

Comment: If you stipulate the exact parameters by which to judge them, this question can perhaps be valid. In other words, instead of giving vague guidelines - "things like willingness to murder" - ask "which of them killed more people." That way you can get specific answers that will allow you to make up your own mind about which of them is more evil.

Comment: @MishaRosnach Reworded

Comment: Related, possibly dupe? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/120520/3567

Comment: Also related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8821/how-many-people-did-voldemort-kill?rq=1

Comment: Also, obligatory "J.K. Rowling is bad at maths" comment.

Answer (score 1):

In the books, it is said that Grindelwald misses out on the spot as the Number One Dark wizard of all time only because Voldemort came along later.

There are no death counts or enough information to be any more precise about it.